# Accessing network share in explorer on different domain not prompting for credentials. Access is denied

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, network-share, windows-explorer

I'm accessing a machine on a different domain in Windows explorer. When I navigate to the machine (ie. \MACHINENAME), I'm able to see all the shares on that machine. I'm not prompted for a username/password. As soon as I try to access one of the shares, I get the error:

```
\\MACHINENAME\SHARE is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resource. Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions. 

Access is denied.
```

However, if I try to access a different machine on the domain, I'm prompted for a username/password as soon as I try to access the machine. This issue is only occurring when accessing shares on this specific machine.

I've tried deleting all connections by running `net use * /del /Y`. There are no entries in "Stored User Names and Passwords". My workaround is to map individual shares to a network drive, but I'd like to have it behave like all other machines on the domain.

This is a Server 2003 VM that is a DC in its own domain.

Thanks.

Comment: what happens if you force a pw request by doing a net use * \\machinename\share * /user:xxx\users

Comment: That did it, thanks! Specifically, `net use \\machinename\share * /user:domain\user`. The * after `net use` mapped the share to a drive, which I was trying to avoid. It also fixed it for all the shares on the machine.

Add it as an answer when you get a chance and I'll accept it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `net use \\machinename\share * /user:domain\username`

Note:

- `share` e.g. `c$`
- `user` is actually "user", `username` is your account name.